# ¿Como agregar un select a mi columna de mi datatable?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, entity-framework, bootstrap-4

Tengo una duda en como agregar un select o un dropdown list a mi columna en mi tabla, me explico en la siguiente imagen muestro el diseño de mi tabla y los input types que utilizo

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y el siguiente código es el siguiente que utilizo para mostrar los diferentes input types, como text, number, etc.

```js
var registro = "<tr>";
            registro += "<td><button type='button' id=Forecast" + indexLinea +" class='btn btn-danger btn-sm' onclick='removeRow(this)'><i class='fas fa-backspace'></i></button></td>";
            registro += "<td><input type='number' class='form-control form-control-sm  PART_ID' value=" + valueLinea["PART_ID"] + " /></td>";
            registro += "<td class='descripcion'>" + valueLinea.descripcion + "</td>";              
            registro += "<td><input type='number' class='form-control form-control-sm  QTY' value=" + valueLinea["QTY"].toFixed(2) + " /></td>";
            registro += "<td class='MULTIPLE_ORDER_QTY'>" + valueLinea.MULTIPLE_ORDER_QTY + "</td>";
            registro += "<td class='UM'>" + valueLinea.UM + "</td>";                
            registro += "<td class='PRODUCT_CODE'>" + valueLinea.PRODUCT_CODE + "</td>";                
            var fecha = valueLinea["Fecha"] == '0001-01-01T00:00:00' ? '' : valueLinea["Fecha"].split('T')[0].split('-').reverse().join('/');
            registro += "<td><input type='text' id='fechaForecast' class='form-control form-control-sm Fecha ' value=" + fecha + " /></td>";
            registro += "<td><input type='text' class='form-control form-control-sm  CUSTOMER_PO_REF' value=" + valueLinea["CUSTOMER_PO_REF"] + " /></td>";
            registro += "<td><input type='number' class='form-control form-control-sm  Destino' value=" + valueLinea["SHIP_TO_ADDR_NO"] + " /></td>";
            registro += "<td class='NAME'>" + valueLinea.NAME + "</td>";
            if (valueLinea.error) {
            }
            registro += "</tr>";

            $("#tablaForecast tbody").append(registro);
```

Lo que quiero hacer que en mi columna **Descripcion destino** mostrar un dropdown list

por ejemplo

```html
<select class="mr-2 browser-default custom-select" id="demanda">
                        <option value="0" disabled selected>Seleccione una opción</option>
                        <option value="pedido">Pedido PDF</option>
                        <option value="almacen">Stock Archivo Excel</option>
                        <option value="forecast">Pedido / Forecast archivo excel</option>
                    </select>
```

quiero saber la mejor forma de agregar que ese select me aparezca en mi columna Descripción destino
espero haberme explicado, si requieren mas información estaré al pendiente

Answer (score 1):

te recomiendo que cambies un poco tu sintaxis para que sea más fácil mantener el código. Te indico los cambios:

```
var registro = "<tr>";
registro += `<td><button type='button' id=Forecast" + indexLinea +" class='btn btn-danger btn-sm' onclick='removeRow(this)'><i class='fas fa-backspace'></i></button></td>`;
registro += `<td><input type='number' class='form-control form-control-sm  PART_ID' value="${valueLinea["PART_ID"]}"></td>`;
registro += `<td class='descripcion'>${valueLinea.descripcion}</td>`;
registro += `<td><input type='number' class='form-control form-control-sm  QTY' value="${valueLinea["QTY"].toFixed(2)}"></td>`;
registro += `<td class='MULTIPLE_ORDER_QTY'>${valueLinea.MULTIPLE_ORDER_QTY}</td>`;
registro += `<td class='UM'>${valueLinea.UM}</td>`;             
registro += `<td class='PRODUCT_CODE'>${valueLinea.PRODUCT_CODE}</td>`;                
var fecha = valueLinea["Fecha"] == '0001-01-01T00:00:00' ? '' : valueLinea["Fecha"].split('T')[0].split('-').reverse().join('/');
registro += `<td><input type='text' id='fechaForecast' class='form-control form-control-sm Fecha ' value="${fecha}"></td>`;
registro += `<td><input type='text' class='form-control form-control-sm  CUSTOMER_PO_REF' value="${valueLinea["CUSTOMER_PO_REF"]}"></td>`;
registro += `<td><select class="mr-2 browser-default custom-select" id="demanda">
                                 <option value="0" disabled selected>Seleccione una opción</option>
                                 <option value="pedido">Pedido PDF</option>
                                 <option value="almacen">Stock Archivo Excel</option>
                                 <option value="forecast">Pedido / Forecast archivo excel</option>
                             </select></td>`;registro += `<td class='NAME'>${valueLinea.NAME}</td>`;
if (valueLinea.error) {
      registro += "</tr>";
      $("#tablaForecast tbody").append(registro);
}
```

Las etiquetas `<td>` no se deben cerrar directamente con `<td/>` además, se deben cerrar siempre con `</td>`.
Por otro lado he actualizado la sintaxis usando `${}` en lugar de abrir y cerrar comillas para cada variable.

Espero que funcione, un saludo.